# React-Navigation - How to track state change in nested navigator only

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I understand there is the `onNavigationStateChange(prevState, newState, action)` prop on top-level navigators, however is there any way to monitor/respond to changes within a nested navigator only?

e.g. Given a hierarchy such as:

- StackNavigator

  - Screen1/TabNavigator

    - Tab1
    - Tab2
    - Tab3
  - Screen2
  - Screen3

How can I monitor changes between the tabs in Screen1 (i.e. nested TabNavigator)?